# ImportError: cannot import name 'cluster_resolver'

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, unity-game-engine, ml-agent

I get this error when trying to setup Unity3d ml-agents

> ImportError: cannot import name 'cluster_resolver'

Following https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/ml-agents/blob/master/docs/Installation.md tutorial

from tensorflow.contrib import cluster_resolver

Error happens when I try to run `mlagents-learn --help`

I am on MacOS with Python 3.6

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by using Tensorflow 1.7.0 instead of 1.7.1 as in the tutorial.